# reduxForm Input file in safari returns an undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dropzone.js, redux-form

I have a reduxForm that contains an input type file, the return value of selected file is undefined my code is:

```
  <Field
     label="Select a File"
     name="file"
     component={this.renderFileField}/>
```

and renderFileField function is:

```
  renderFileField( field ){

return(

      <div>
        <label className="label">{field.label}</label>
        <label htmlFor="file" className="input input-file">
          <div className="button mystyle-btn-u">
            <input type="file" id="file" {...field.input}
            value={null}
            onChange={(e)=>
              {
                field.onChangeExtra();
                //remove fakepath string from file name that would display in input
              ReactDOM.findDOMNode(e.target).parentNode.nextSibling.value = e.target.value.replace(/.*fakepath\\/,"");
                //fileName value would set with file name user selected from file picker
              this.setState({fileName:e.target.value.replace(/.*fakepath\\/,"")})}}
            ></input>
            Browse
          </div>
          <input
          value={this.state.fileName}
           type="text" onChange={this.ChangeFileName.bind(this)}/>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I also tried Dropzone input file but in safari on click file chooser not shown but with drag and drop file can be select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is how:

1) It's important to note that  Doesn't support the setting 
   of values, so if you want to bind the values back to something you'll need to 
   write a custom "selected files" component.

2) You need to do some parsing of the event before calling fields.yourField.handleChange(). Something like this:

```
<input
  type="file"
  onChange={
    ( e ) => {      
      e.preventDefault();
      const { fields } = this.props;
      // convert files to an array
      const files = [ ...e.target.files ];
      fields.yourField.handleChange(files);
    }
  }
/>
```

3) Do your validation in the normal way

Comment: Thanks for your response, it helps me a lot  :)

Comment: I don't know the true way to set fields.yourField.handleChange(files);

Comment: the value in the validation is empty.

Comment: @Mahsa you can store your values into you local state. Instead of `field.yourField.handleChange(files)` you can create your own funciton and store the value in state and on button click validate the value inside state. like `this.state.files`

Comment: I set field.input.onChange(files) and get the correct responce. this link also was helpful: http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/faq/CustomComponent.md/

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is coming from you calling setState from inside of your onChange handler. extract that out into a separate function and bind it or use a class property, i.e.

```js
onChange = () => {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried that but still get the same result.